# PDF keywords from Expl3 clist

Tags: hyperref, pdf, expl3, comma-separated-list

I’m trying to add PDF keywords to my résumé. In the custom class file, I have these lines:

```
\clist_new:N \jcsres_keywords_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \keywords {m} { \clist_gset:Nn \jcsres_keywords_clist {#1} }

\AtBeginDocument{
  \hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
      Author={\jcsres_name_tl},
      Keywords={\jcsres_keywords_clist},
    }
  }
}
```

The `\keywords` command is intended to be used in the document preamble, like `\author` and `\title` in the standard classes. My hope was to initialize it with a standard comma-separated list, and pass the list more-or-less directly to `\hypersetup`.

The code above, though, seems (from looking at the PDF in Adobe Reader) to have a single keyword, of the form `"keyword1,keyword2,"`—not at all what I’m hoping for.

According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization, the syntax `\hypersetup` expects is

```
pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3},
```

Is there a straightforward way to translate between Expl3’s clists and this syntax?

ETA: User g.cov [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115372/2966) the use of [`hyperxmp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp); I may well use that package, but I’d like to learn how to do the transformation on my own using Expl3. In particular, please note that

```
Keywords = { \clist_use:Nnnn \jcsres_keywords_clist
               {\egroup \bgroup} {\egroup \bgroup} {\egroup \bgroup} }
```

did *not* work.

Comment: I think l3prop is more suitable for your situation.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, perhaps as an Expl3 replacement for the entire `pdfinfo`; but for the `Keywords` list, a clist seems most apropos.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon After seeing your edit, I've added a different version that seems to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The other PDF viewers (okular, evince) seem to show the list OK,
but it seems that only `hyperxmp` helps to fix this for `Adobe Reader`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\keywords#1{\def\k@yw@rds{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfkeywords={\k@yw@rds}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\keywords{LaTeX update, clist item}

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to *use* the comma list variable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_jcsres_keywords_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \keywords {m} { \clist_gset:Nn \g_jcsres_keywords_clist {#1} }

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \hypersetup
   {
    pdfinfo=
    {
     Keywords={\clist_use:Nnnn \g_jcsres_keywords_clist {,~} {,~} {,~} },
    }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\@onlypreamble\keywords % don't allow \keywords in the document
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}

\keywords{LaTeX3, clist}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to pass the list of keywords each enclosed in braces without commas in between, as it appears to be the best way for using them, here's the way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_jcsres_keywords_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \keywords {m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
   { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_jcsres_keywords_seq { {##1} } }
 }

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \hypersetup
   {
    pdfinfo=
    {
     Keywords={\seq_use:Nnnn \g_jcsres_keywords_seq {~} {~} {~} },
    }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\@onlypreamble\keywords
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}

\keywords{LaTeX3, clist}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\end{document}
```

Here's what I get now in Adobe Reader:

[image]

Comment: Another function we need to decide about moving to 'stable' :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Possibly with a "shorthand" `\clist_use:Nn` for `\clist_use:Nnnn` when the three `n` arguments are the same. And also for `\seq_use:Nnnn`: the case when you need the same token list to be inserted between all two items is perhaps more common than the one where you need to distinguish between "two items" and "more than two items".

Comment: I think we already have `\seq_use:Nnnn` or similar in the 'candidates'. I'll raise this with the rest of the team: I think it's a 'definite yes' for the stable part.

Comment: @JosephWright After all it's just `\cs_new:Npn \seq_use:Nn #1 #2 { \seq_use:Nnnn #1 { #2 } { #2 } { #2 } }`

Comment: While I agree that it is semantically better to use `\clist_use:Nnnn` here (and that we should move it to be stable), why would it make any difference (I can't test here)?  The only thing this `\clist_use:Nnnn` does is to add spaces after each comma in the list.  I would have expected an expansion issue to be at the origin of the OP's problem.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Indeed, I get the same information in Adobe Reader, that is the keywords enclosed in double quotes. However, normalizing the keywords to be also space separated seems better. There's no expansion issue, because `pdfinfo` interfaces with the `\pdfinfo` primitive of pdfTeX, that fully expands its balanced text argument.